# PHP hyperclick package for atom text editor

Tags: php, composer-php, atom-editor

Atom editor have a [hyperclick](https://atom.io/packages/hyperclick) package.

I was trying to build a package which can

Open the file when the user press `Ctrl` + `left click` on a class name from the file. See the [demo of hyperclick](https://atom.io/packages/hyperclick)

My initial thoughts was to rely on composer.

I have a few things with me,

The current opened file path, the string that the user clicked, and line number.

Eg : Assume we have a class as

```
<?php
namespace Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('posts');
    }
}
```

and user clicks on `Table` , the idea is to open the `Cake/ORM/Table.php` from the appropriate location with the help of composer `findFile()` method.

```
<?php
$loader = require '/current/project/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->findFile('Table');
```

Then I understood `Table` is not the FQCN, so we need to get the FQCN which is `Cake\ORM\Table`. Is there a way we can get the FQCN from the current things I have?

I had a look at Reflection, but it also need FQCN. I wished if we can relay very less on 3rd party packages. Eg , some of you may suggest to look at the https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser . If there is any other way ( easy pc ;) ) let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenize the current PHP file using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token-get-all). Then:

- Discover if the clicked string is a FQCN (e.g. when using `new \a\b\Something();`, look at `T_NS_SEPARATOR` and `T_STRING` tokens)
- Find all `T_USE` tokens before the `T_CLASS` token and see if one of these are directly linked to `Table` (e.g. `use a\b\Table;` or `use a\b\c as Table;`, look also at `T_AS`)
- Prepend the current namespace by parsing all none-whitespace token between `T_NAMESPACE` and `';'`

Comment: Thank you :) . On the way :) .

Comment: Your answer have something that I may not have, eg : as the case you mentioned if the class name used was with new \a\b\c , for currently I only have c as the string. I may want to do something getting the string from the js itself and parse then :) .